# Error passing php array with json_encode to js handler

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I declare php arrays, i fill them with strings taken from query.
I have to pass this arrays to a handler of a element in the page.
Handler can't read this arrays.

PHP:

```
    $names = $paths = $infos= [];
    $i = 0;
    while($row = $result->fetch_row())
    {
            $names[$i]= $row[0];
            $paths[$i]= $row[1];
            $infos[$i]= $row[2];
            $i++;
    } 
    ...
    for($i = 1; $i < ($length/8)+1  ; $i++)//arrotonda per eccesso
    {

        $jsNames = json_encode($names);
        $jsInfo  = json_encode($infos);
        $jsPaths = json_encode($paths);
        //echo $jsNames."<br>";
        //echo $jsInfo."<br>";
        //echo $jsPaths."<br>";
        ?>
        <a href="#" onClick="changePhoto(<?php echo $i.','.$jsNames.','.$jsInfo.','.$jsPaths ?>)" class="w3-bar-item w3-white w3-button"> <?php echo $i ?></a>
```

JS:

```
function changePhoto(num,names,paths,infos){
 //nothing
 }
```

Browser error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }`

Opening browser debugger: 
       `(function(event){changePhoto(2,[     })`

Comment: What return commented `echo`es?

Comment: can you pease update total code clearly

Comment: I bet you have a problem with quotes here. Your jsons will have `"` in it. So try to change `onClick="..."` to `onClick='....'`

Comment: Should the  last } be a ] in `(function(event){changePhoto(2,[     })`

Comment: but why are you including _all the values_  anyway? You really need that?Or could you just make it `echo $i.",'".$names[$i]."','".$infos[$i]."','".$paths[$i]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have a problem with quotes here. Your jsons will have some " in it, and your html-attribute is enclosed in ", too. 
So change

```
onClick="changePhoto(<?php echo $i.','.$jsNames.','.$jsInfo.','.$jsPaths ?>)"
```

to

```
onClick='changePhoto(<?php echo $i.','.$jsNames.','.$jsInfo.','.$jsPaths ?>)'
// note the single-quotes here!
```

*Sidenote:*
You should put these lines `$jsNames = json_encode($names);` outside the loop, as they won't change anymore. But now you're doing the same work several times.